# Querying another post category to match current post and display in loop

Tags: posts, customization, loop, array

I'm trying to query a custom post type's category to display in another custom post type, but only if they have matching categories.

I'm new to coding a fairly complex WordPress site from scratch (it's fun) - I think I am probably typing the query wrong - any help will be appreciated.

```
    <section id="meet-team">

    <div class="container">

        <h2>Title will be custom field</h2>
        <p class="lead">custom field text will be in here</p>

    <div class="row">

       <?php $category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
```

$cat_id = $category->cat_ID; ?>

```
      <?php get_posts($args =array(
                           'posts_per_page' => 2, 
                           'post_type' => 'team', 
                           'category' =>$cat_ID)  ); ?> <!-- this is the bit I think I am struggling with -->


     <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


<div class="col-6">

    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) { $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ); ?>

    <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" alt="<?php the_title() ?>">

                <h3><?php the_title() ?></h3>
                <p><?php the_excerpt() ?></p>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"></a> 


</div><!-- col -->



         <?php } ?>

        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

        </div><!-- row -->

    </div><!-- container -->
</section><!-- meet-team -->

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: are you using the code in a category archive template? otherwise, `get_query_var( 'cat' )` will not be defined.

Comment: I've made my own single template for my custom post type. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes. I added an answer based on that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are adding the custom query into the single template, try working with [`get_the_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) to get the cat_id for your query; 
also, [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) does not work with `if( have_posts() )` etc.

example code, using a custom query:

```
   <?php 
   $cat = get_the_category();

   $cat_id = $cat[0]->term_ID; 

   $cpt_match_query = new WP_Query( array(
         'posts_per_page' => 2, 
         'post_type' => 'team', 
         'cat' => $cat_id) ); 

  if ( $cpt_match_query->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $cpt_match_query->have_posts() ) : 
    $cpt_match_query->the_post(); 
  ?>

    YOUR OUTPUT SECTION

  <?php 
    endwhile;
  endif; 
  wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>
```

the above does not take care of the html tags in your code, which also need to be readjusted.

Comment: Ah this is great, I will try it this morning. Cheers :)

Comment: you are a star! I need to do some css with it but it works, awesome! :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your posted code, you have a mismatch in your variable`$cat_id`.  In the first instance, where you assign a value, it is all lowercase:

```
$cat_id = $category->cat_ID;
```

In your query args, you have capitalized the ID portion:

```
'category' => $cat_ID  <-- does not match your earlier var
```

Comment: Ah right, yes I see - I have changed it to lower case - I still draw a blank on the posts displaying.

Comment: Print that var before using as a query param.   Does it contain the category ID you expect?

Comment: No, just blank. I think I must have something else wrong?

Comment: will it be easier to match slug or something? I'm not sure how to do that but they will both obvs use the same slug - could match by cat ID/slug. I feel like this is missing from my query. I basically need to pull in posts from the matching category of another custom post type.

Comment: It needs to:

query and identify current custom post category, 
query posts from another custom post type, 
display posts matching current category,